# Is there a keyboard shortcut to Edit files such as .reg, .bat, and so on?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, editing

I think the answer is no, but I have asked to be sure. For files such as .reg or .bat, one can right click on them and then choose Edit, which opens the file in notepad, rather than execute the file. Is there a keyboard shortcut for Windows that can do that?

Comment: As long as you consider the context menu button followed by E a shortcut, yes. The context menu button is usually located somewhere to the right of the spacebar, on my keyboard between right-start and right-ctrl. E should be the shortcut for the Edit menu item, but may differ depending on your language.

Comment: Shift+F10 is another way of accessing the right click menu. You can use arrow keys or `e` as in Berend's comment to edit the file.

Comment: What about the Edit button Explorer in the Ribbon in Windows 8? Is there a keyboard shortcut for that? I know that I can add it to the Quick Access toolbar and then use Alt + the number position it's at, but besides that, is there a direct keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> edits your file in Notepad++.

*Explanation:*
3 commands:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> (brings up context menu)
2. <kbd>N</kbd> (selects Notepad++)
3. <kbd>Enter</kbd> (opens up Notepad++)

Type this in one go and it edits your file in Notepad++.

Comment: Possible update: as of today, on Windows 10 you can open the file in your default editor using `Shift + F10`, `E` (for Edit)